# How to create an instance of a class and inject dependencies without registering it in DryIoc?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dryioc

I need to create an instance of a class with some parameters **without registering it in the container**, as I often need to get some classes with the dependencies injected without them cluttering the container.

Here is an example:

```
interface IPrinter
{
    void Print(string text);
}
class ConsolePrinter : IPrinter
{
    public void Print(string text) => Console.WriteLine(text);
}
class Thing
{
    public Thing(IPrinter print, string otherParameter)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Register<IPrinter, ConsolePrinter>();

        // This throws.
        container.Resolve<Thing>(args: new object[] { "something something" });
    }
}
```

I get an exception: `DryIoc.ContainerException: 'code: UnableToResolveUnknownService`, which makes sense.

I can sure just do `container.Register<Thing>()`, but as said before, it would add an unwanted service to my container.

Comment: Is `otherParameter` a runtime argument, or is it known (and fixed) during the time the container is being registered? This information is essential for being able to answer your question.

Comment: It's a runtime argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to set [WithConcreteTypeDynamicRegistrations](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RulesAndDefaultConventions.md#withconcretetypedynamicregistrations) rules for container.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though with this code: `rules.WithConcreteTypeDynamicRegistrations((_, serviceKey) => "meow".Equals(serviceKey), Reuse.Singleton)`, and doing `container.Resolve<Thing>(args: new object[] { "something something" }, serviceKey: "meow")`, the lambda is evaluated **twice**, first with the actual `serviceKey` (`"meow"`), and then with `serviceKey` being `null`, which leads to a resolve failure. But without comparing the `serviceKey`...!

Comment: Please create an issue with this info in DryIoc github repo.

Comment: [Here is the issue](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/issues/248)